# Finding closest value before current time in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 8 hrs shifts like this in my table `Shift` and `shiftstart` and `shiftend` datatype as `time(7)`.

```
ShiftNo ShiftName  ShiftStart  ShiftEnd  IsNextDay  IsBothNextDay
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    Shift1     7:00:00     14:59:59   0          0
   2    SHift2     15:00:00    22:59:59   0          0
   3    Shift3     23:00:00    7:00:00    1          0
```

If I execute the procedure at 07:10, I should get shift3 row

```
23:00:00.0000000-07:00:00.0000000 as timestamp
```

My existing procedure is

```
declare @shift table
(
    shiftno     int,
    shiftstart  time(7),
    shiftend    time(7)
)

--  sample data
insert into @shift 
values (1, '07:00', '14:59:59'),
       (2, '15:00', '22:59:59'),
       (3, '23:00', '07:00:00')

DECLARE @Currenttime AS TIME

SET @Currentdate = GETDATE()  
SET @Currenttime = (SELECT CAST(@Currentdate AS TIME))
SET @PreviousShifttime = (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, -8, @Currenttime))

--  the query
; with shifts as
(
    select  *, 
        shift_start = convert(datetime, shiftstart),
        shift_end   = case  when shiftstart < shiftend
                    then convert(datetime, shiftend)
                    else dateadd(day, 1, convert(datetime, shiftend))
                    end
    from    @shift
)
select *
from shifts
where convert(datetime, @PreviousShifttime) between shift_start and shift_end
   or dateadd(day, 1, convert(datetime, @PreviousShifttime)) between shift_start and shift_end
```

This procedure is returning the current shift row correctly. But I want previous shift rows without hardcoding -8 hrs based on nearest value of shift start in previous shift end

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @shift table(
    shiftno     int,
    shiftstart  time(7),
    shiftend    time(7)
)

insert into @shift values
(1, '07:00', '14:59:59'),
(2, '15:00', '22:59:59'),
(3, '23:00', '06:59:59') -- I changed shiftend here

SELECT p.*
FROM @shift c
JOIN @shift p ON c.shiftstart=DATEADD(SECOND,1,p.shiftend)
WHERE CAST(GETDATE() AS time) BETWEEN c.shiftstart AND c.shiftend
```

The second variant:

```
declare @shift table(
    shiftno     int,
    shiftstart  time(7),
    shiftend    time(7)
)

insert into @shift values -- I changed all the shiftend here
(1, '07:00', '15:00'),
(2, '15:00', '23:00'),
(3, '23:00', '07:00')

DECLARE @CurTime time=CAST(GETDATE() AS time)

SELECT p.*
FROM @shift c
JOIN @shift p ON c.shiftstart=p.shiftend
WHERE @CurTime>=c.shiftstart
  AND @CurTime<c.shiftend
```